# Convert XML to Object using reflection

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

If you like problems to resolve, here a big one :D

First, It isn't about serialization, ok?

Well, my situation... I am writting a function that I will pass as parameter a Xml (XmlDocument) and an object (Object) as reference. It will return to me a object (object that was referenced) filled with the values from the Xml (XmlDocument).

For example:

I have a Xml like:

```
<user>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Daniel</name>
</user>
```

Also I have my function

```
public Object transformXmlToObject (XmlDocument xml, Object ref)
{
  // Scroll each parameters in Xml and fill the object(ref) using reflection.
  return ref;
}
```

How will I use it?

I will use like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument RecebeLoteRPS(XmlDocument xml)
{
  // class user receive the object converted from the function
  User user = new User();
  user = transformXmlToObject(xml, user);

  // object filled 
}
```

I need help guys, please.

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: Sounds like it's about serialization to me - XmlSerializer-ation to be precise.  But perhaps not.

Comment: How is this not serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, yes, this is exactly about serialization. In fact, this is exactly what XML serialization was written for.

Anyway, if you want to write your own, perhaps you can set properties based on the tags in your XML blob? i.e. if you User object has an `Id` and a `Name` property, perhaps you should set them in accordance with the XML blob?

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you want.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
    public class XMLHelper
    {
        public static void HydrateXMLtoObject(object myObject, XmlNode node)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
            IEnumerator list = node.GetEnumerator();
            XmlNode tempNode;

            while (list.MoveNext())
            {
                tempNode = (XmlNode)list.Current;

                propertyInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(tempNode.Name);

                if (propertyInfo != null) {
                    setProperty(myObject,propertyInfo, tempNode.InnerText);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `User` is an already-defined object with properties to be filled in with the XML data, then yes, this is an XML serialization problem.

If you want `User` to be an object with dynamic structure based at run-time on the XML data, then take a look at `ExpandoObject` in .NET 4.0. It should be possible to traverse the XML tree and build an equivalent tree of `ExpandoObject` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this is indeed about Serialization, and should be what you're looking for. However, to pique your interest about querying XML documents the easy way, have a look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some type validation in the answer posted by @andyuk. So that for each property, it will lookup the property type and then try to convert the xml value so that no exceptions will be thrown.

But still you need to make sure that xml data should have same type of data which you are inserting as property value. You can do by xsd file for your xml file, or just ignore it if you know about your data and it won't change.

```
                    var pi = entity.GetType( ).GetProperty( eleProperty.Name.LocalName );
                    if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof( DateTime ) )
                    {
                        DateTime val = DateTime.MinValue;
                        DateTime.TryParse( ele.Value, out val );
                        pi.SetValue( entity, val, null );
                    }
                    else if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof( Int32 ) )
                    {
                        int val = 0;
                        Int32.TryParse( eleProperty.Value, out val );
                        pi.SetValue( entity, val, null );
                    }
                    else if ( pi.PropertyType == typeof( bool ) )
                    {
                        bool val = false;
                        Boolean.TryParse( eleProperty.Value, out val );
                        pi.SetValue( entity, val, null );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pi.SetValue( entity, eleProperty.Value, null );
                    }
```