# how to extract data from an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have two classes called Movie and Movie Type and im trying to create objects of that classes based on the given example xml.

```
public class Movie
{
  public string title;
  public string rating; //can always convert.toin32 later
}

public class Genre
{
 int id;
 string genreType;
}
```

I would like to create objects of that class based on the following XML, what would be the best/fastest way?

```
<movie> 
<title> se7en </title> 
<genre> thriller</genre> 
<rating> 18 </rating> 
</movie> 
<movie> 
<title> zodiac </title> 
<genre> thriller</genre> 
<rating> 18 </rating>
</movie>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert XML to Object using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268912/convert-xml-to-object-using-reflection)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Xml File for Records using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422431/query-xml-file-for-records-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Better will be `LINQ` to `XML`

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("MyDoc.xml");

List<Movie> statusList = (from movies in document.Descendants("Movie")
                           select new Movie()
                            {
                               title = movies.Element("title").Value,
                               rating = movies.Element("rating").Value,
                               genre = movies.Element("genre").Value
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: what if you was split across two classes? e.g.
    class Movie{
    string movie;
    string rating;
    }
   class Type
   {
    string Genre;
   }
   }

how would that be done considering you can create one new object in the select new Movie()

Answer (score 2):

or this

```
var xml = @"<movie/>";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var movie = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```