# Conditional XML serialising based on type in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, types, conditional-statements

Is there an easy way to use the `ShouldSerialize` pattern to conditionally serialize class properties based on their type without having to write `ShouldSerializeX()` functions for each property?

Basically, I have many classes each with many properties that need to be serialized but I only want to add them to the XML document if they have certain values. Writing `ShouldSerializeX()` for each property in each class is error-prone, cumbersome and annoying.

e.g.

- for `string`s, if they are empty or null, then don't serialize
- for `bool?`, if it is null, then don't serialize
- for `List`s, if they are null or have a count of 0, don't serialize.

Comment: It is more error prone to use other approaches.  You could create custom XML serialization and use Reflection and make the code even harder to read and understand.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269081/214977     it could be the starter-kit..and you can add your custom rules.